# How to import in Typescript/Javascript at runtime synchronously?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamic-import

I have a class in Typescript in which I am trying to make a synchronous import but the import is getting asynchronously . I am trying this :

```
--------------100 lines of code--------------------

import('../../../x/y/z').then((x) => { 
     alert('Component')
});

--------------100 lines of code----------------------
```

But using this method alert is getting printed at the end i.e after the 200 lines get execute(asynchronously because internally Promise is getting used) but I want to execute it in the given serial order.
Is there anyway by which it can be executed serially provided the import has to be dynamic.

Thanks

Comment: Async code cannot be converted to synchronous. You either need to make *everything* async or rethink your approach.

Comment: In node.js you can make synchronous imports using `require` instead of `import`, but why not just make your code asynchronous? Put the 100 lines that need the imported module inside the `then` callback.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to import ahead of time and call syncronous functions from the modules you import.

```
// hello.js
export default function hello() { return "Hello, world!" }

// index.js
import hello from "./hello"
hello()
```